# Nx console is using ng instead of nx as the runner for the commands, how can I change it?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, nrwl-nx, nrwl

The title is pretty self explanatory.
There is a large project that has been built with nx a couple of years ago, where nx console works.
however, when running the commands, it is attempting to run them doing `npx ng...`
instead of `npx nx...`

as a result, since we are using angular 14 and nx 14, most of the commands don't work (like creating a new component, or a new library, or running lint or tests) because my angular.json file is version 2 (instead of v1 as expected by Angular's ng CLI)

The error I keep getting is

```
Invalid format version detected - Expected:[ 1 ] Found: [ 2 ]
```

Comment: do you have some form of `decorate-angular-cli.js` script in place?

Comment: you should get credit for pointing me in the right direction, I'm noticing just now I didn't mention this comment in the answer!. 
The answer is no, I didn't have any decorate-angular-cli.js and that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to generate a demo project to post here and answer the comment posted in my question, I realized that by default `NX` seems to use the `ng` command runner for most of the generator commands.

Upon reading thoroughly [their documentation](https://nx.dev/more-concepts/nx-and-angular), I fixated in the fact that the `nx` CLI decorates `ng`, making `nx` and `ng` interchangeable.

Then I remembered not long ago while cleaning up the `package.json` file, I removed the `decorate-angular-cli.js` file from the root of my project, along with the postinstall command.

For reference:

- if you generate any angular nx project, you'll get a file named decorate-angular-cli.js in the root of your project folder, and a postinstall script in your package.json that loks like this:

  "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js"

So for me, restoring the file and the postinstall command did the trick.
It did not make `nx console` use `nx` instead of `ng`, but instead it made the `ng` commands run as if they were `nx` (bc `nx` and `ng` are in fact interchangeable, only after running the contents of the file `decorate-angular-cli.js`)

*Edit: thx [@Andrew Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4711754/andrew-allen) for pointing me in the right direction with your comment.*

Comment: for me the script was "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main"